# loss.backward() in pytorch stops responding when using GPU

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using pytorch in an environment built on WSL.
When I train a deep learning model on the GPU(RTX3090) as shown below, it stops responding at `loss.backward()`.

After pytorch stops, the GPU occupancy is 0% and `nvidia-smi` stops responding.

```
def train_loop(model, optimizer, scheduler, loader, device):
   losses, lrs = [], []
   model.train()
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   for i, d in enumerate(loader):
       print(f"{i}-start")
       out, loss = model(d['X'].to(device), d['y'].to(device))
       print(f"{i}-goal")
       losses.append(loss.item())
       step_lr = np.array([param_group["lr"] for param_group in optimizer.param_groups]).mean()
       lrs.append(step_lr)
     
       loss.backward()
       optimizer.step()
       optimizer.zero_grad()
       scheduler.step() 

   return True
```

ex. Stopped on the 45th batch.

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
device
-> device(type='cuda', index=0)

train_loop(model, optimizer, scheduler, train_loader, device)
-> 0-start
   0-goal
   ...
   43-goal
   44-start
```

I'd like you to tell me why it's not working.

Comment: Does 'stops responding' mean there is no error message and you are stuck in some infinite loop?

Comment: + Could be irrelevant to your issue, but `scheduler.step()` is expected to be called at each epoch, not each step(unless custom defined).

Comment: Yes. No error message is displayed and the process does not proceed.

Comment: + Thanks. Commenting out `scheduler.step()` did not help.

Comment: Have you checked the GPU memory usage? How much is used? Does it keep growing during training or does it keep constant?

Comment: GPU memory usage have not changed during training.

Comment: What is the size of `loader`?

Comment: It is 117, and the size of dataset is 60,360.

Answer (score 0):

In PyTorch we explicitly set the gradients to zero before starting to do back-propragation pass for each mini batch.

I cannot confirm that accumlating too much gradients on the subsequent passes is the cause to your problem, but there is a high chance. Moreover, in this way you mix up the gradients between mini-batches which will affect the model performance

So, `optimizer.zero_grad()` has to be inside your training loop.

Comment: In my `train_loop` function, it looks like I'm running `optimizer.zero_grad()` in the training loop. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Yes; however, I meant inside the mini-batch looping.

Comment: How can I do `optimizer.zero_grad()` inside the mini-batch looping?

Comment: Moving the line inside `for i, d in enumerate(loader):` loop?